# Infinite$-$state absorbing Markov chains

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, markov-chains

Could someone provide a good reference/book about **infinite$-$state** absorbing Markov chains? Most of what I've found so far deals only with the finite$-$state case.

Comment: You are correct that the theory of Markov Processes becomes much different once one moves away from finite state spaces and discrete time, where n x n transition matrices 'rule'. The subject is vast and varied. Perhaps the simplest situations are gambler's ruin and absorbing birth-death processes, for which web searches might suffice. More exotic situations are in the convergence of Gibbs Samplers, where it seems there are unresolved issues of practical importance. It get a useful response for _your_ purposes, you should say more specifically what you have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Standard reference is Meyn and Tweedie "Markov Chains and Stochastic Stability" which is also now freely available online (first edition). You can start from it, and dig into references if needed - each chapter is concluded with a comprehensive history/literature review.